# Creating Azure storage container fails when deploying on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring, azure, weblogic12c

I have a very simple spring boot project for testing that successfully creates a container in an existing Azure Storage Account when running standalone. But when deployed in a WebLogic 12c server it fails with an error I can't find on the internet.

The proyect has a Controller, an Application, a weblogic.xml and the pom.xml, nothing more. when running it locally works perfectly, creating a container with the connection string of the account (with de account key) and the name of the container.

Here is the code of the Controller class:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createAzureContainer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void createAzureContainer() 
            throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException, InvalidKeyException {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
                CloudStorageAccount.parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" + 
                        "AccountName=[accountName];AccountKey=[accountKey]");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("[containerName]");
        container.createIfNotExists();
        container.downloadAttributes();
    }
}
```

And the code of the Application class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

This is the weblogic.xml, located in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>demo</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

And finally the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

With this anyone with an Azure Storage Account can try to run standalone and create containers. But when deploying to a WebLogic 12c the following line:

```
        container.createIfNotExists();
```

fails with the following exception, which sounds to me like the problem you may have when uploading a blob, but can't find any reference about it in the internet searching about containers:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The server encountered an unknown failure: Length Required
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:101) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.create(CloudBlobContainer.java:261) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExists(CloudBlobContainer.java:385) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.createIfNotExists(CloudBlobContainer.java:326) ~[azure-storage-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.DemoController.createAzureContainer(DemoController.java:66) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:12.2.1.2]
```

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: I've found that the problem is in a incompatibility between Microsoft Azure java library and the implementation of webLogic of the class **HttpURLConnection**, being this **weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection** instead of the one from Tomcat **sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection**.

The former lacks the **Content-Length** and causes the error.

I've tried to get webLogic to use that implementation with the server start parameter **-DUseSunHttpHandler=true** to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information & Azure Storage offical [error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/common-rest-api-error-codes), the issue was caused by missing `Content-Length` header, please see below.

[image]

You can try to use Fiddler to check the error code `411` & response to make sure the issue reason when the exception happened.

Per my exception, I think WebLogic server caused the missing `Content-Length` header issue. I searched and discovered WebLogic server use some strategies for backward-compatibility to use own implementation for some standard like `JAX-RS`, `JAX-PRC`, etc.

So I think you can try to refer to Oracle offical document [`Invoking Web Services from Client Applications and WebLogic Server`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/client.html) & [`Fusion Middleware Developing and Securing RESTful Web Services for Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3`](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/toc.htm) to resolve the issue.

Some solutions I think may help resolving it.

1. According to the document [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/client.html), trying to add the code below.

   ```
   // Setup the global JAX-RPC service factory
   System.setProperty( "javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory", "weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.ServiceFactoryImpl");
   ```
2. Try to [`Configuring the Web Application to Use Jersey 2.5.1 (JAX-RS 2.0 RI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF300).
3. Try to refer to [`Developing RESTful Web Service Clients`](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/develop-restful-client.htm#RESTF143) to change or setup for your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! First things first, thank you for your time and effort. I've tried the points 1 and 2 to no avail. I'm going to edit the question with more information about the problem now that I have refined it. Cheers!